# non vr project with leap motion and ue4

Tags: virtual-reality, unreal-engine4, leap-motion, unreal-blueprint

Does anyone know how to setup a leap motion for a non VR project.

Also I want it to be orientated frontside down 45 degrees.

There almost no documentation about this on the internet, anyone some experience?

Many thanks,

Olivierus

Answer (score 0):

The Leap controller is already available in UE4 (definitely in 4.14.3 and probably earlier). In the editor, go to Edit->Plugins and search for Leap. That should enable reading the input events.

Next, you need to make arms and fingers articulate to follow the Leap inputs. Tbh I cannot remember if there are Leap-ready models in Engine Content, but once you enable the plugin you should see the Leap content as well. Look in there, or google "getnamo leap ue4" for his old Leap-UE4 implementation. That's where I got my models from.